# Setting timeouts in Spring Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

Application is using Spring rest template to call a webservice and i am using
    restTemplate.exchage(url)     to call the webservice.
Currently we are not passing any timeout value for this webservice call, How can i set a timeout value for Spring Rest template.

Comment: http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-set-http-request-timeouts-with-spring-resttemplate/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use code similar to following for setting connection timeout:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setConnectTimeout(2000);
```

If your wish to set read timeout, you can have code similar to following:

```
((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)restTemplate.getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(2000);
```

The time is given in milliseconds here. For more info, you can visit the [documentation page](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html).

Answer (score 5):

RestTemplateBuilder introduced since Spring 1.4 could be used to set read and connect timeout settings for RestTemplate object. Here is sample code -

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate =
    new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectTimeoutMillis))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeoutMillis))
        .build();
```

Comment: This is the right way! Other responses rely on modifying HttpClient, which can fail in runtime (i.e: implementation would not be available in your JVM). The downside: RestTemplateBuilder belongs to Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach based on these threads

```
int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5000;
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
 .setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
 .setConnectionRequestTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
 .setSocketTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
 .build();
```

`CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
     .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
     .build();`

[Spring RestTemplate Connection Timeout is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909219/spring-resttemplate-connection-timeout-is-not-working)

[Java : HttpClient 4.1.2 : ConnectionTimeout, SocketTimeout values set are not effective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725492/java-httpclient-4-1-2-connectiontimeout-sockettimeout-values-set-are-not-ef/11903054)