# How to shorten time of refused connection?

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

Sometimes my server doesn't work and HttpClient tries to connect about 180 seconds before connection is refused. Is there any way to shorten this time?

Comment: your tag is ambiguous, please select the right one (see on tag hover info)

Comment: I found clear answer is : [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on android:

```
int socketTimeoutMS = 120000;
new DefaultHttpClient().getParams().setIntParameter("SO_TIMEOUT", socketTimeoutMS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the timeout value?

Integer timeoutMs = new Integer(5 * 1000);
messageSender.getHttpClient().getParams().setSoTimeout(timeoutMs);

Comment: also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132326/with-apache-httpclient-why-isnt-my-connection-timeout-working?rq=1

Comment: Apache HttpParams in Android hasn't got method setSoTimeout(timeoutMs). It is my fault that my tag was ambiguous. Thank you for help.