# httpclient timeout for many requests

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

To simulate a webapplication with many users, I have used a for loop, I know still its very different as this will be single thread and all that. My code is below

```
public CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() {
        try{
            SSLContext context = null;
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            } };

            try {
                context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            } catch (KeyManagementException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(context, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                      .register("https", sslConnectionFactory)
                      .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();

            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
             // Increase max total connection to 200
             cm.setMaxTotal(20);
             // Increase default max connection per route to 20
             cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
             RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
                        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                        .build();
             CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                     .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).build();
            return httpClient;
        }catch(Exception ce){

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then in loop I am using it like below

```
try{
for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
                client = getHttpClient();
request = new HttpPost("Some https URL");
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
              int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
 if (statusCode == 200 ){
                    entity = response.getEntity();
                    String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
                else{
                    entity = response.getEntity();
                    String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}}
catch(Exception ce){}
finally{
                  try {
                        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                        request.releaseConnection();
                        client.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
              }
```

I get response for few request whereas fail for few with read timeout, if I increase the max connection I get few failures If I keep max conn as 200 in connection manager still I get few failure but not as many as with this config, WHAT is that I am missing. Exception below

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:903)
>           at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
>           at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
>           at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
>           at com.ibm.indo.serviceImpl.GenericServiceImpl.checkDomRegNew(GenericServiceImpl.java:233)
>           at com.ibm.indo.controller.ReportsController.checkDomRegNew(ReportsController.java:45)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>           at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Try setting a lock on the request. I dont see any lock on the resource(http client) in your code

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that your https server is able to handle 200 connections smoothly?.
I feel, the issue is not with your httpsClient Code. Server may refuse to accept few request because of load on it?.

Answer (score 1):

as Exception below it is clear that httpclient is not able to make a socket connection. httpclient tries to establish a connection but within the pre-define time for connection establishment it fails to connect.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) at
```

Please check this

With Apache HttpClient, [why isn't my connection timeout working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132326/with-apache-httpclient-why-isnt-my-connection-timeout-working)

http://brian.olore.net/wp/2009/08/apache-httpclient-timeout/

Comment: the problem may resolved by increase connection-time-out or by using maximum connection to handle the request.